# Configurar para Eclipse mostrar nome dos parâmetros no auto-completar

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

As vezes o eclipse, ele mostra no auto-completar os nomes das variáveis de um jeito mais fácil de entender. Por exemplo, se nessa linha em pressionar ctrl+Espaço :

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage();
```

Ele mostra entre outros **BufferedImage(int width,int height, int imageType)**

Mas se eu uso algo do JavaFX as vezes não aparece, por exemplo se eu usar :

```
PixelWriter pw = writableImage.getPixelWriter();
pw.setArgb();
```

Ele mostra : **pw.setArgb(int arg0,int arg1,int arg2)**

Tem como configurar isso, pra mostrar mais fácil em todos?

Comment: Está utilizando a ultima versão do Eclipse? Tente também atualizar o Code Recommenders, ele é o responsavel pelo code complete, se der certo avise aqui https://eclipse.org/recommenders/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na view **Project Explorer** expanda o seu projeto e depois expanda o item **JRE System Library**. Nela você encontrará um item chamado **jfxrt.jar**, clique com o botão direito e selecione a opção **Properties**. Isso irá abrir uma janela de diálogo das properiedades desse jar.

Na jenala procure o item **Javadoc Location**. Marque a opção **Javadoc URL** e coloque: `https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/`. Clique em **Apply** e você poderá ver o javadoc dos métodos e classes.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou